# Trying to log into PowerSchool website using Mechanize (Python) - failing

Tags: python, authentication, webforms, mechanize, powerschool

I'm trying to log into our *PowerSchool* server through Python and Mechanize, but I can't seem to successfully do it. A tricky part of this is that the login form only has a single field for inputting both my username and password, separated by a semicolon. Here is the webpage: https://powerschool.laalliance.org/admin/home.html

Can someone tell me if my code is correct?

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(False)
br.addheaders = [("User-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0")]
br.open('https://powerschool.laalliance.org/admin/')

br.select_form(name='LoginForm')
br.set_all_readonly(False)
#br.find_control('pstoken').readonly = False
#br.form['pstoken'] = '123123asdfasdf123123'
br.form['password'] = 'jdoe;' + pw

br.method = 'POST'
response = br.submit()
print response.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

Checked the website, and if you do right-click on the form, then 'inspect element' you will see that the name of the form is : "password"

Hence, you should replace your line:

```
br.select_form(name='LoginForm')
```

to

```
br.select_form(name='password')
```

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Actually, just tried your original code, and I get the following among other things: "Invalid Username or Password! Attempt has been recorded." Looks like it should be working, since I got no password and that is why my login attempt fails.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't thought to look for an error message. Once I saw that the page returned was a robots page, I just assumed the login failed. I guess now I have to figure out how to avoid being detected as a robot. Thanks for that tip, I Want Badges (lol your name).